# Regular expression - two numbers together

Tags: regex

I have string:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

I need this sequence of numbers divided into a pair.

The output should look like this:

```
[
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6],
  [7,8],
]
```

I am trying this regular expressions:

```
/(([\d]+)[,\s]([\d]+)[,\s]?)+/
```

In php:

```
preg_match_all('/(([\d]+)[,\s]([\d]+)[,\s]?)+/', $item['cords'], $matches);
```

but output match is only two last numbers - 
https://regex101.com/r/oV2nQ4/1

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: If you look at your own example, you will see that it works if you remove the `+` at the end.

Comment: Why overcomplicate it? Use multiple matching with `\d+(?:,\d+)?` or `\d+,\d+` (depending on what you want to do if the numbers are not even). See [this demo](https://ideone.com/aPWJot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get the groups by a quantifier. Capture the two numbers and use the global flag instead.

Try this:

```
(\d+),(\d+),?
```

[Like this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/oV2nQ4/3).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8';

var regex = /(\d+\,\d+)/g;

var r = str.match(regex).map(e => e.split(',').map(Number));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(r) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This pattern just matches single-digit numbers. For example it doesn't match `11,12`

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this tested `sed` command:

```
 sed -e 's/\([0-9],[0-9]\)/[\1]/g' -e 's/^\(.*\)$/[\1,]/' -e 's/[[][[]/[\n  [/' -e 's/[]],/],\n  /g' -e 's/  []]/]/g'
```

The test:

```
$ printf "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\n" | sed -e 's/\([0-9],[0-9]\)/[\1]/g' -e 's/^\(.*\)$/[\1,]/' -e 's/[[][[]/[\n  [/' -e 's/[]],/],\n  /g' -e 's/  []]/]/g'
[
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6],
  [7,8],
]
```